# Multiple partial results in a UWP app service

Tags: c++, uwp

I am trying to use an [UWP app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) to provide some non-UI processing service to other app *including the host app*. For responsiveness, I want to return the result progressively. Think about `grep`-ping a folder for files containing a certain string: It would be better to report the files as we found it instead of reporting everything at the end.

So my question is: Can this scenario be achieved with the current UWP technology? (I think it is probably possible via polling using the multiple app instances approach. I want to know if there's an easier method with app service.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppServiceConnection is a bi-directional communication pipe, so you can use it to communicate progress updates from the service to the client. No need for polling. Just retain a reference to the AppServiceConnection instance in your service implementation once the client has connected and then call [SendMessageAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appservice.appserviceconnection.sendmessageasync) to send progress updates to client whenever you want.